# Correct classes not attaching to angularjs accordion and HTML not rendering correctly

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm trying to implement something like:

[http://embed.plnkr.co/3y0Rq1/](https://embed.plnkr.co/3y0Rq1/)

The plumbing is all connected, the groups are getting output, and each group is getting the class `ng-scope`, but my HTML isn't getting the class `accordion-group`. It's getting `ng-binding` instead. Also, my HTML is getting rendered as `<accordion-group>` and `<accordion-heading>` instead of as `<div>`s. I think that's key, but I don't know why it's happening. The application to which I'm adding the accordion already appears to have the correct file references, although the versions are newer than in the example at the link I provided. The end result is that the HTML that is rendered is just text. It's not formatted correctly and doesn't expand and contract like an accordion. Here's my code.

References in Index.cshtml (the app is being launched from ASP.NET MVC):

```
maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
~/Content/dist/css/app.css
code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js
maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-route.js
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-cookies.min.js
cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.5.7/angular-sanitize.min.js
Scripts/angular-sortable-view.js
~/Scripts/angular-auto-focus.js
Scripts/ui-bootstrap-custom-tpls-2.0.1.min.js
~/Content/dist/js/app.min.js
~/Scripts/angular-img-http-src.js
```

Accordion.js

```
(function (angular) {
    angular.module("profilebuilder")
        .controller("Accordion",
            [
                "$scope", function($scope) {
                    $scope.groups = [
                        {
                            title: "Dynamic Group Header - 1",
                            content: "Dynamic Group Body - 1",
                            open: false
                        },
                        {
                            title: "Dynamic Group Header - 2",
                            content: "Dynamic Group Body - 2",
                            open: false
                        }
                    ];
                }
            ]);
}(angular));
```

HTML:

```
<div class="SearchCriteria" ng-controller="Accordion">
    <accordion>
        <accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups" heading="{{group.title}}" is-open="group.open">
            <accordion-heading>
                {{group.title}}
            </accordion-heading>
            {{group.content}}
        </accordion-group>    
    </accordion>
</div>
```

Correct HTML:

[image: Correct accordion HTML]

Incorrect HTML:

[image: Incorrect accordion HTML]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the version you are using of the ui.bootstrap

this html will work

```
<uib-accordion close-others="oneAtATime">
  <div uib-accordion-group class="panel-default" heading="{{group.title}}" ng-repeat="group in groups">
      {{group.content}}
    </div>
  </uib-accordion>
```

Here is the link to a [plknr](http://embed.plnkr.co/6PFFb7LHg0bYZ3rN7pNB/) wit example